# Socket: Disposing connection twice?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to work this one out but it really is a head scratcher, a socket is meant to make two connections to the server, the second one being the legitamate connection. I have this method that I attach to my callback for beginReceive method although its calling Dispose twice?

Usually it only calls it once as the client makes 2 connections to the server, the second one being legitamate but it seems this method wants to call Dispose twice, which makes me think theres something wrong, could somebody verify if there is anything wrong with this?

```
private void OnIncomingData(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    int bytesReceived;

    try
    {
        bytesReceived = _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
    }
    catch
    {
        Dispose();
        return;
    }

    if (bytesReceived == 0)
    {
        Dispose();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        var packet = new byte[bytesReceived];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, packet, bytesReceived);

        var received = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(packet);
        var packetData = JObject.Parse(received).ToFlatDictionary();

        var incomingPacket = new IncomingPacket(packetData);
        CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Received packet: " + incomingPacket.Id + "\n\n" + received);

        if (_session.PacketProvider.PacketEvents.TryGetValue(incomingPacket.Id, out var packetEvent))
        {
            packetEvent.Invoke(_session, incomingPacket);
            CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Finished executing packet " + packetEvent.GetType().Name + " for " + incomingPacket.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Failed to execute unknown incoming packet: " + incomingPacket.Id);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get an exception in your last big `try/catch`, it will call `Dispose` in the `catch` and then again in the `finally` block.